# TCPDF: MultiCell when auto addpage

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm doing a report with TCPDF, but in MultiCell when a new page is generated characters are mounted on another. How I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with out seeing code this cannot be answered!

did you follow the examples on tcpdf website  - multiple page formats

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_028.phps

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_020.phps